# Trying to create 16x16 grid with flexbox but for some reason width: 100% won't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I'm trying to create a 16x16 grid with flexbox. I have set the width property of every 17th element to 100% and `flex-wrap` to `wrap` to achieve this. However, for some reason, my code doesn't work. I don't get the 16x16 grid on my page. How can I solve this?

```js
const cdiv = document.querySelector('.container');

// Add 16 divs
for (let i = 1; i < 257; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; height: 25px; width: 25px";  
  cdiv.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div:nth-child((16n + 1)) {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: I don't get the desired 16x16 grid @Sfili_81

Comment: Please add a working example using the SO snippet, so we can inspect what is not working

Comment: @Sfili_81 what's a SO snippet and how do I add it?

Comment: check `.container>div:nth-child((16n + 1))` is wrong. Try this `.container>div:nth-child(16n + 1)`

Comment: @Sfili_81 oh it made things even worse. Is there a different way to create a 16x16 grid with flexbox?

Comment: Something like this? [https://jsfiddle.net/e2bqyts0/](https://jsfiddle.net/e2bqyts0/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your nth child (extra brackets) - if you remove this and then unstyle, your 17th divs, you should get your grid:

```js
const cdiv = document.querySelector('.container');

// Add 16 divs
for (let i = 1; i < 257; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  cdiv.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(16n + 1) {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You could just make the js do it for you depending on an input:

```js
function createBoxes(numberPerRow) {
  const cdiv = document.querySelector('.container');
  const total = (numberPerRow * numberPerRow) + numberPerRow;
  const mod = numberPerRow + 1;

  for (let i = 1; i < total; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');

    if (i % mod === 0) {
      div.style.cssText = "border: 0; height: 0; width: 100%";
    } else {
      div.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; height: 25px; width: 25px";
    }

    cdiv.appendChild(div);
  }
}

createBoxes(16);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you set `border` and `height` to 0 inside `container>div:nth-child(16n + 1)`?

Comment: so the div doesn't take any space and just acts as a break to push the next lot onto a new row

Answer (score 1):

If you are not absolutely required to use flexbox, use grid. Grid is perfectly suited to this application:

```js
const cdiv = document.querySelector('.container');

// Add 16 divs
for (let i = 1; i < 257; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; height: 25px; width: 25px";  
  cdiv.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 25px [col-start]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine except it creates 15 columns and 16 rows.
Took me a while to figure it out but it should be:

a) `"i < 273(257+16)"`

and

b) `.container>div:nth-child(17n + 1)`

The reason being your 1st, 18th, 35th, and so on divs are being used to expand the whole thing.

So your boxes without the fix actually go from 2th to 14th (15 columns) divs.