# How do I make my divs show up when created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to create a 16 by 16 grid by using DOM manipulation and the dynamically created divs aren't showing up. I tried assigning a background-color but it didn't work.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let k = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.display = 'flex';
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    newDiv.id = k++;
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: container is the name of the div class I have. edited

Comment: add some `height` to your div as well. without content, the `div` will remain 0 in height, making it not visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to create 16x16 grid with flexbox but for some reason width: 100% won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943484/trying-to-create-16x16-grid-with-flexbox-but-for-some-reason-width-100-wont-w)

Comment: Flagged this question as duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69943664/17911862

Answer (score 1):

It is because the divs are adding but they are empty, add something to the div to see them appear...

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let k = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.display = 'flex';
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    newDiv.id = k++;
    newDiv.textContent = "x";
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Or you can also add height to see them appear...

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let k = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.display = 'flex';
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    newDiv.id = k++;
    newDiv.style.height = "5px";
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```